# SQLITE3 prepare not evaluating to SQLITE_OK in C

Tags: c, server

if been wondering around this question for a while now. Ive been reading the man pages and some good related to this problem. But the found solutions were not feasible.

Im trying to follow a tutuorial on a simple server in c.

At this point of code we introduced a SQL Database and added some Users.
Now we want to print out the List of all Users, if a User asks for it.

My Problem is that the prepare function is not evauating to SQLITE_OK.

```
// list all users
strcpy(buf,"All users\n");
send(sock, buf, strlen(buf),0);

// Query databse for all users
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
char *query = "select uname from users order by uname";
// prepare DB
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,query,strlen(query),&stmt,NULL)== SQLITE_OK){ 


--> ABORTING at this point...

    // display list to client
    while (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    sprintf(buf, "%s\n", (char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
                    send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

            }
    // Send "."
    strcpy(buf,".\n");
    send(sock,buf,strlen(buf),0);
}
```

Is there anything you have in mind, what I did wrong here?
I also copied the code from the tutorial into my files -> same problem..

I hope you can help me

greetings

Comment: Use sqlite3_errmsg or similar to get the underlying error, and post that here if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: I used the errmsg like this: printf("%s",sqlite3_errmsg(db)); --> No print out / no error.
and I left out the if statement.
Now the while is sending NULL -> infty

Comment: It's not clear what you've done. Please change your code to print the error message if the prepare fails (i.e. in the else branch).

Comment: @mat can I do the "does it look like im going down the stairs" move?
I was refering to the wrong table / empty table... Wrong set path... Thanks anyway  -.-